# How to take particular character from a string and store it in a array

Tags: typescript

var element = "Connectorparent3cchild4d"
element.match(/\d+/g)

previously the code has written to take numeric value from the string

but now var element = "Connectorparent**abc**child**cd**"

is there any way to store the value abc and cd in a array

I need to store the value which is after Connectorparent and child in an array in typescript

Answer (score 0):

You might first remove "Connectorparent" and split on "child" to get both `abc` and `cd` in an array

```js
var element =  "Connectorparent3cchild4d"
const arr = element.replace("Connectorparent", "").split("child");
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `/Connectorparent(.*)child(.*)/` as yours regex:

```js
var element = "Connectorparent3cchild4d"
const [all, parrent, child] = element.match(/Connectorparent(.*)child(.*)/)
```

You can read about groups in regex to better understand, or use https://regexr.com/ to explain or build yours regexs.